# Issue creating a function within a class

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to set up a new class with a play() function.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because I have other classes which I have implemented in similar ways, and they work fine.  Can somebody point out where I may have made an error?

.h file

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Game {
public:
Game(); 
void play();
};
#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "game.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Game::Game() {}

Game::play() {}
```

I call the play function as follows:

```
Game* theGame = new Game();
theGame->play();
```

I am getting the following errors when I compile:

```
game.cpp:10: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘play’ with no type
game.cpp:10: error: prototype for ‘int Game::play()’ does not match any in class ‘Game’
game.h:16: error: candidate is: void Game::play()
game.cpp:10: error: ‘int Game::play()’ cannot be overloaded
game.h:16: error: with ‘void Game::play()’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First error:

```
Game::play() {}
```

should be

```
void Game::play() {}
```

Second one - you have `using namespace std;` in your header. Never do that. Not an error per-say, but bad practice.

Third - you have `#include <string>` in the header, although you don't use `string`, so it's useless and can impact compilation time.

Fourth - you use `new` :). Please google *smart pointers*. This is C++ and raw pointers usage should be at a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the return type:

```
void Game::play() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Game::play() {}
```

you should add type: void as a return type.